# How to create foreign key relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

I would like to enforce the creation of the foreign key below:

[image]

This is what I've [tried](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

```
[ForeignKey("AlertFieldId")]
public virtual ICollection<AlertCriteria> AlertCriteria { get; set; }
```

How do we enforce that a specific foreign key is created?

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use [IEntityTypeConfiguration](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api#separate-configuration-classes)s to specify a [ForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key) reference.

But automatically specifying AlertFieldId and AlertField Props in AlertCriteria class you automatically creates a FK (after executing migrations, but if already exists in BD, it would works if you include (.[Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-5.0#code-try-1)) in query)

As Follows:

```
public class AlertCriteria
{
    public int AlertFieldId { get; set; }
    public AlertField AlertField { get; set; }
}
```